# How to understand such sample in GNU ld manual about linker script?

Tags: gnu, ld, binutils

I am learning the GNU linker ld script [sample about memory region alias](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/REGION_005fALIAS.html#REGION_005fALIAS).

I see the following ld script snippet:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    } > REGION_TEXT

    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata)
        rodata_end = .;
    } > REGION_RODATA  <=========== PLACE 1

    .data : AT (rodata_end) <=========== PLACE 2
    {
        data_start = .;
        *(.data)
    } > REGION_DATA <=========== PLACE 3

    data_size = SIZEOF(.data);
    data_load_start = LOADADDR(.data);

    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    } > REGION_BSS
}
```

One possible system memory region layout given in the sample is like this (*C* in that sample):

```
MEMORY
    {
        ROM : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 2M            /*0M ~ 2M*/
        ROM2 : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 1M  /*256M ~ 257M*/
        RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 1M   /*512M ~ 513M*/
    }

REGION_ALIAS("REGION_TEXT", ROM);     /*0M ~ 2M*/
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_RODATA", ROM2);  /*256M ~ 257M*/
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_DATA", RAM);     /*512M ~ 513M*/
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_BSS", RAM);      /*512M ~ 513M*/
```

So,

`PLACE 1` says `.rodata` MUST go into `REGION_RODATA`, that is `256M~257M`

`PLACE 2` says the `.data` section MUST be placed ***immediately*** after the `.rodata` section. So `.data` section MUST start from ***at most*** 257M.

But `PLACE 3` says the `.data` section MUST goes into the `REGION_DATA` region. So `.data` section MUST start from ***at least*** 512M.

So how could it be possible?

Comment: Can you link some example with this script and dump section info from it using readelf/objdump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concepts to understand this example are those of **Virtual Memory Address (VMA)** and **Load Memory Address (LMA)**.

[The GNU Linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Basic-Script-Concepts.html#Basic-Script-Concepts) official documentation defines those two terms as follows.

> Every loadable or allocatable output section has two addresses. The
>   first is the **VMA**, or virtual memory address. This is the address the
>   section will have when the output file is run. The second is the **LMA**,
>   or load memory address. This is the address at which the section will
>   be loaded.

In the example, for all output sections but `.data`, the VMA and LMA addresses are the same. For section `.data` the LMA is specified by `AT (rodata_end)` while the VMA address is the first available address of the `REGION_DATA` memory region.

With this in mind, we can read again the example and see that it leads to the situation represented below.

```
ROM (alias REGION_TEXT)
+---------+------------------------------+
|  .text  |                              |
+---------+------------------------------+

ROM2 (alias REGION_RODATA)
+-----------+---------+--------+
|  .rodata  |  .data  |        |
+-----------+---------+--------+

RAM (alias REGION_DATA)
+---------+--------+-----------+
|  .data  |  .bss  |           |
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

The `.data` section appears twice: once in `ROM2` and once in `RAM`. It is put at its load address (LMA) when loaded; subsequently it is moved to its virtual address before running the program.
By the way, this is why, a few line later in the documentation you mentioned, we can read that

> It is possible to write a common system initialization routine to copy
>   the .data section from ROM or ROM2 into the RAM if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Could you help see this question? It's related to VMA and LMA and the location counter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341040/how-to-decide-the-base-address-for-the-location-counter-when-vma-and-lma-are