# How to decide the base address for the location counter "." when VMA and LMA are different?

Tags: gnu, ld, binutils

According to the ld manual [on the special symbol `.`, i.e.the Location Counter](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Location-Counter.html#Location-Counter).

> Note: . actually refers to the byte offset from the start of the
>   current containing object. Normally this is the SECTIONS statement,
>   whose start address is 0, hence . can be used as an absolute address.
>   If . is used inside a section description however, it refers to the
>   byte offset from the start of that section, not an absolute address.
>   Thus in a script like this:
>
> ```
>  SECTIONS
>  {
>      . = 0x100
>      .text: {
>        *(.text)
>        . = 0x200
>      }
>      . = 0x500
>      .data: {
>        *(.data)
>        . += 0x600
>      }
>  }
> ```
>
> The '.text' section will be assigned a starting address of 0x100 and a
>   size of exactly 0x200 bytes, even if there is not enough data in the
>   `.text' input sections to fill this area.

And the ld manual also says about [output section's VMA and LMA](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Basic-Script-Concepts.html#Basic-Script-Concepts):

> Every loadable or allocatable output section has two addresses. The
>   first is the VMA, or virtual memory address. This is the address the
>   section will have when the output file is run. The second is the LMA,
>   or load memory address. This is the address at which the section will
>   be loaded. In most cases the two addresses will be the same. An
>   example of when they might be different is when a data section is
>   loaded into ROM, and then copied into RAM when the program starts up
>   (this technique is often used to initialize global variables in a ROM
>   based system). In this case the ROM address would be the LMA, and the
>   RAM address would be the VMA.

**So my question is:**

**If an output section is specified with different VMA and LMA, what's the base address for the byte offset `.` ?**

In the below example, the `.data` section has different VMA and LMA. My understanding is `PLACE 1` specify the `LMA` is in `ROM2`, while `PLACE 2` specify the `VMA` is in `RAM`? So what's the base address for the `.` symbol within the `.data` section?

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    } > REGION_TEXT

    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata)
        rodata_end = .;
    } > REGION_RODATA

    .data : AT (rodata_end) <=========== PLACE 1
    {
        data_start = .;
        *(.data)
    } > REGION_DATA <=========== PLACE 2

    data_size = SIZEOF(.data);
    data_load_start = LOADADDR(.data);

    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    } > REGION_BSS
}
```

The memory layout is below:

```
MEMORY
    {
        ROM : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 2M            /*0M ~ 2M*/
        ROM2 : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 1M  /*256M ~ 257M*/
        RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 1M   /*512M ~ 513M*/
    }

REGION_ALIAS("REGION_TEXT", ROM);     /*0M ~ 2M*/
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_RODATA", ROM2);  /*256M ~ 257M*/
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_DATA", RAM);     /*512M ~ 513M*/
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_BSS", RAM);      /*512M ~ 513M*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question one can make use of two facts from the official `ld` documentation.

First fact from [Output Section LMA](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html#Output-Section-LMA).

> The following linker script creates three output sections: one called
>   `.text`, which starts at `0x1000`, one called `.mdata`, which is loaded
>   at the end of the `.text` section even though its VMA is `0x2000`, and
>   one called `.bss` to hold uninitialized data at address `0x3000`. The
>   symbol `_data` is defined with the value `0x2000`, which shows that **the
>   location counter holds the VMA value, not the LMA value**.

```
 SECTIONS
   {
   .text 0x1000 : { *(.text) _etext = . ; }
   .mdata 0x2000 :
     AT ( ADDR (.text) + SIZEOF (.text) )
     { _data = . ; *(.data); _edata = . ;  }
   .bss 0x3000 :
     { _bstart = . ;  *(.bss) *(COMMON) ; _bend = . ;}
 }
```

Second fact from [The Location Counter](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Location-Counter.html#Location-Counter).

> **. actually refers to the byte offset from the start of the current
>   containing object**. Normally this is the `SECTIONS` statement, whose
>   start address is `0`, hence `.` can be used as an absolute address. If `.`
>   is used inside a section description however, it refers to the byte
>   offset from the start of that section, not an absolute address.

Putting together these two pieces of information, one can say that the location counter specifies a VMA value by giving its offset from the start address of the current containing object (`SECTIONS` statement or output section).

So the **absolute** base address for the location counter is

- the start address of the `SECTIONS` statement – that is `0` – if we refer to `.` outside an output section definition
- the VMA of an output section if we refer to `.` inside
  that output section

As for the `.data` section in your example, you’re right: `PLACE 1` specifies the LMA is in `ROM2` while `PLACE 2` specify the VMA is in `RAM`.

Since the location counter, when used inside a section description, refers to the byte offset from the start of that section, the base address for the `.` symbol within the `.data` section is `0`. However this is a relative address and it corresponds to the absolute address `0x20000000` which is the VMA of the `.data` section. By the way, this is coherent with the fact stated above that `PLACE 2` specifies the VMA is in the `RAM` memory region (alias `REGION_DATA`).
If your example were a real one, you could easily check what has just been stated by using the `ADDR(section)` linker script language builtin function to get the VMA for the `.data` section.

Comment: Thanks. I refined the example in my question to clearly state my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

After I read a few more ld scripts, I came to the following understanding:

I wrote the below snippet for illustration of *section declaration statement*.

[image]

So as illustrated above, the `section` declaration in a ld script has 2 important things to specify:

- the LMA at load time
- the VMA at run time

We can specify these addresses in 2 ways:

- precisely at a specific address
- or append to a memory region

These 2 ways have different positions in the *section declaration statement* as shown above, before or after the curly brace.

A section itself is a **RIGID BODY**. The location counter `.` **ONLY** stands for the offset within its containing object.  **No more, no less**. **It's neither VMA nor LMA.**

The offset's base can be either VMA or LMA of the containing section, **depending on it is runtime or loadtime your are talking about.**

But in a symbol assignment statement like below or other symbol manipulations with in a section declaration, **VMA is used a the base of `.`**.

```
  .data_flash     : {_data_flash = .;} >CODE
```

Comment: I figured this out back then. And I need to read my own reply to understand it now...